# (Bash) Regex variable inside another regex

Tags: regex, bash, variables

I am writing on a script which greps with a regular expression and includes another regular expression with a variable. But there it seems to lay the problem.

Script ($hostname is an argument from command line and can be i.e. google.com):

```
tldlist="$(curl -s http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt | grep -v '#' | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/|$//g')"

curl="$(curl -vfIk https://$hostname 2>&1 | sed 's/^\* \t //g' | grep -i -o --color=never -E \"CN=\(.*\)\.\($tldlist\)\")"
expiration="`curl -vfIk https://$hostname 2>&1 | sed 's/^\* \t //g' | grep -i -E --color=never '(start|expire)'`"

echo "$curl"
echo "$expiration"
```

It just does not match the part with the common name in the output of curl.
If I write the regex manually, it works and matches successfully.

So the question is: How to solve this regex problem inside bash?

**Update**
Now I tried to write it in another way, it works (basically):

```
curl=$(curl -vfIk https://$hostname 2>&1 | sed 's/^\* \t //g' | grep -i -o --color=never -E "CN=(.*)\.($tldlist)")
```

The problem lays at escaping the quotes and brackets. But I have to put the output of the command into double quotes due to multiline variables (not with the line above, this just gives you one line).

**But still:**
There is the question how to solve the escape/regex/variable problem.

Comment: Can you provide output of `curl -vfIk https://$hostname 2>&1` command?

Comment: I added the whole script.

Comment: @thonixx: you don't have to escape `"` inside of `$(...)`, or even inside of `"$(...)"`. Within the `$(...)`, you are effectively inside a new lexical context.

Comment: D'oh.. I think I thought the wrong way in this case for the whole time. Now it is clear again.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is not a regex issue.  You have your `$tldlist` variable inside single quotes, and single quotes prevent variable expansion.  Change your second line to, e.g.:

```
curl="$(curl -vfIk https://$hostname 2>&1 | sed 's/^\* \t //g' | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | grep -i --color=never -E "CN=\(.*\)\.$tldlist")"
```

so as to allow `$tldlist` to expand.

Comment: I updated my question and posted the script. I had to escape the " and ( and ) in order to get it work. It now does not match either. And with your exact example there are some command substitution errors due to unexpected token.